# PDO php two statements in one function, if both are true commit else rollback

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Working with PHP PDO, there are two statements, the idea is if both stmt1 
and stmt2 are true it should commit otherwise it should roll back, but as I see here it's not getting rollback and here if the stmt1 is true it will comment even the stmt2 is false.

this is the function:

```
 public function insert() {

            //  try { $stmt1 = $this->conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
            $this->conn->beginTransaction();
            $stmt1 = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT into table1 (item,itemname,price)VALUES (:name, :itemname, :price)");

            $stmt1->bindParam(':name' ,                  $this->name);
            $stmt1->bindParam(':itemname' ,              $this->itemname);
            $stmt1->bindParam(':price' ,                 $this->price);
            $stmt1->execute();

            $stmt2 = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT into table2 (item,itemname,price) VALUES (:name, :itemname, :price)");

            $stmt2->bindParam(':name' ,                  $this->name);
            $stmt2->bindParam(':itemname' ,              $this->itemname);
            $stmt2->bindParam(':price' ,                 $this->price);
            $stmt2->execute();

            //} catch(PDOException $r){ echo $r->__toString();exit; }
            if($stmt1 && $stmt2){
                $this->conn->commit(); //This will save  changes
            } else {
                $this->conn->rollBack(); //This will undo  changes
            }

        }

    }
```

Here i checked in this function if the stmt1 is true it will run and insert data into table one even the stmt2 is false

Question : how i can keep like it should run stmt1 and then stmt2 and if stmt1 is false it should not run stmt2 and if stmt2 is false it should rollback stmt1 also.

thanks in advance.

Comment: from the sounds of it, this logic should not be hurting your brain.

Comment: Why have you removed part which works with exceptions? You could place commit after last execute and rollback into catch block.

Comment: With current logic you could `if ($stmt1->execute() && $stmt2->execute())`. Anyway you need to check result of execute...

Comment: is it possible that there is already a transaction started on the connection when your function is called ?

Comment: @sectus, i am trying you solution

Comment: @lan kenney do i need to lock before transactions, will it not slow the transaction?

Comment: @sectus, this work for me here....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
public function insert() {

        //  try { $stmt1 = $this->conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
        $this->conn->beginTransaction();
        $stmt1 = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT into table1 (item,itemname,price)VALUES (:name, :itemname, :price)");

        $stmt1->bindParam(':name' ,                  $this->name);
        $stmt1->bindParam(':itemname' ,              $this->itemname);
        $stmt1->bindParam(':price' ,                 $this->price);
        //$stmt1->execute();

        $stmt2 = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT into table2 (item,itemname,price) VALUES (:name, :itemname, :price)");

        $stmt2->bindParam(':name' ,                  $this->name);
        $stmt2->bindParam(':itemname' ,              $this->itemname);
        $stmt2->bindParam(':price' ,                 $this->price);
        //$stmt2->execute();

        //} catch(PDOException $r){ echo $r->__toString();exit; }
        if($stmt1->execute() && $stmt2->execute()){
            $this->conn->commit(); //This will save  changes
        } else {
            $this->conn->rollBack(); //This will undo  changes
        }

    }

}
```